# WSL2 in vscode does not show the distro name on the left-bottom of the status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

as the title says, my vscode does not show the distro name, even with all necessary plugins installed, while on the other computer, it is fine. (My OS is win11), the methods i have tried:

- reinstall vscode;
- delete all extension in $USER and reinstall;

all of them do not work.

How to let vscode show the distro name on the vscode's status bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a regression in VS Code. It was track by [vscode-remote-release/issues/8770](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8770) and was fixed.